# Upgrade Windows 2008 r2 OEM to Windows 2012r2 Action Pack

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, upgrade, oem

We have the following scenario.

1. old production server with software + configuration which we wish to retire to a testing box but keeping all the current settings etc / app installs.
2. Windows Action pack subscription and Windows 2012 r2 Standard licence

Can we do a live upgrade from 2008r2 64bit > 2012 r2, will the upgrade work or will it fail?

I've read somewhere , but now cannot find the link, that you need to use a different MS upgrade key or sorts ?

Ideally we want to prove the upgrade from 2008 > 2012 works as we have some customers in this situation (although they would not be using action pack key etc)

Comment: Is this a physical server or is it a virtual machine?

Comment: This is a physical server. Dell R720 , no virtualisation on it at all.

Comment: An in-place upgrade from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2012 R2 is definitely supported from a technical standpoint. I have no insight on the licensing aspect of your question. If you have a virtualization host handy you could simply run a conversion tool to create a VM from the server and test your upgrade on the VM.

Comment: I do have an R720 with 2012r2 and Hyper-V running , so this sounds a good idea. Now to find out how to do a physical > vm transfer!

Comment: There are a few utilities that will do a P2V conversion. Here are links to two such utilities: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx and https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42497